# SSRS 2016 external images not displaying when using AWS Route53 HTTPS URL

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, reporting-services, https, ssrs-2016

I have 2 Windows EC2 instances with SQL 2016 and SSRS installed on it with SSL certificate. These 2 instances are under the target group of an NLB. The NLB is referenced using the Route53 HTTPS URL. Same SSRS database has been deployed on both the instances. We have configured our .NET application to point to Route53 URL so that in case an instance goes down, we don't have to update our application to repoint to new instance.

So the issue that I'm having is that the external images on SSRS reports do not show up when using the Route53 https URL either using Report Manager URL in the browser or via Report Viewer in my .NET application, when I have only 1 instance under the target group in NLB. But when I view the report using the server name (EC2 name), the images are displayed both in the browser and through .NET application. The images have been uploaded on the SSRS server and are referenced as external image using an expression (as I need to pick different image based on a condition). I have tried different image types like .png, .gif, .jpg but still no luck. (The reason why we can't use 2 instances with NLB for SSRS is that NLB cannot handle sticky session and therefore we encounter inconsistent results. As a workaround to that we decided to use 1 instance under the NLB target group.)

When using Route53 URL, I get the following error in the Report Server log file:

> An error occurred retrieving the external resource 'https://wtam.ssrs.test.lz081.awsnp.national.com.au/ReportServer?%2fCIMSReporting%2fJAN_Logo.png&rs:Command=GetResourceContents' : Unable to connect to the remote server

Using server name in our application won't be a feasible option as that would not use HTTPS/SSL and therefore the data in transit won't be secure. Thanks in advance

Comment: The URL you've given doesn't work for me either, which does strongly suggest it doesn't exist. That, or the host doesn't allow connections apart from White Listed IPs, and your AWS server (and obviously mine) aren't in them.

Comment: The URL is not a public URL. It is hosted within our AWS account and available internally to authenticated users. Therefore you wouldn't be able to access the URL